# Unwanted setter of virtual string property, in derived class

Tags: c#

Is there a better way of doing the following ...

I have a base class which provides a default implementation of the `DisplayName` property. Obviously optionally set, not required.

**Edit**: I can't use an interface instead of this base class, because I have behavior in it, which is trimmed out in this example.

```
public abstract class BaseObject
{
    public virtual string DisplayName { get; protected set; }

    public BaseObject(string displayName)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(displayName))
        {
            this.DisplayName = displayName.Trim();
        }
    }

    // There is common behavior, unrelated to DisplayName here ... trimmed out of this sample code.
}
```

I have a system object class, derived from `BaseObject`, but providing its own implementation of `DisplayName`

```
public class SystemObject : BaseObject
{
    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("TODO: Resources.{0}", this.Id);
        }
        // EDIT: Turns out I can't even do that, because EF can't materialize the property. So, it needs to be an empty protected setter.
        protected set { throw new InvalidOperationException("Do not set this property!"); }
    }

    public SystemObject() : base(null)
    {
    }
}
```

and I have a user-defined object, derived from the same base class:

```
public class UserObject : BaseObject
{
    public UserObject(string displayName) : base(displayName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(displayName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("displayName");
        }
    }

    public void ChangeDisplayName(string newDisplayName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newDisplayName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("newDisplayName");
        }

        this.DisplayName = newDisplayName.Trim();
    }
}
```

which utilizes the `DisplayName` from `BaseObject` to store a user-provided display name.

I can't make the `DisplayName` in `BasObject` abstract, because I am doing EF code first.

I am particularly concerned about `protected set { throw new InvalidOperationException("Do not set this property!"); }`. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: ``private set`` ?

Comment: private set or no set. Why are you doing all this? Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve? What are your specific concerns about throwing that exception?

Comment: If I do `private set` I can't manage that property anymore from `UserObject`. My concern is that I would prefer if `SystemObject` did not expose a setter on that property at all. Especially a `protected` one.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Well, it's creating an interface that's a lie.  Rather than exposing operations that don't work, you should just not be exposing operations that you can't perform at all.

Comment: IMHO: It sounds like youre painting yourself into a corner with a very brittle design.  Consider following some of the advice presented here to save yourself future headaches.

Comment: @Servy I was asking OP why he wrote the code that way, thanks.

Comment: OP, it looks like you have a case where setting `DisplayName` is OK, and a case where it's absolutely forbidden. That's two different semantics for `DisplayName`. If it were me, I'd probably make `DisplayName` readonly and have one branch of subclasses that have a separate read/write `Name` property that `DisplayName` returns.

Comment: Even worse, seems like I can't actually throw an exception in the protected setter, because then EF can't materialize the property and I get an exception ...

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an abstract class at all when you don't actually want to define any behavior.  If you just want a way of saying that there are different objects with a `DisplayName` property getter, then create an interface that defines such a contract that these two classes can implement in their own ways.

Comment: I have a lot of behavior, it's just trimmed out in that example, I have only left the portion I am concerned about.

Comment: @HristoYankov I can only answer the question that's asked.  This is the correct solution to the problem that you actually presented.

Comment: OK, I have updated my question to specifically say that it has to be a base abstract class.

Comment: Does the trimmed down behavior modify the DisplayName property?

Comment: @HristoYankov So you're asking how to avoid doing [thing] but there's a strict requirement that the code must do exactly [thing], and there can't be any variation on it.  Obviously you can't not do [thing] if the code has to do [thing].  Odds are pretty high that an abstract class isn't what you want; it's pretty rare that it's a good solution to any given problem, but if you insist on this being a non-abstract property in an abstract class, you can't not have it in an inheriting class.

Comment: @HristoYankov Still don't see any reason why you shouldn't be using an interface here.  You've only continued to show *more* behavior that only makes sense for one class and not another.

Comment: There is a common behavior, which is not posted and is unrelated to `DisplayName`.

Comment: @HristoYankov Then create static methods that accept the interface to perform those operations.  You can even make them extension methods if you want.  I still don't see any indication that inheritance is the appropriate behavior here.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see where you are going with this.

Leave the property alone. Just make it a get-only property in the base class, but make the getter call an abstract method:

```
public string DisplayName { get { return GetDisplayName(); } }
```

Then declare the method as abstract:

```
protected abstract string GetDisplayName();
```

That will force your inheriting classes to provide an implementation of how to return a display name. You can then change your UserObject class to store the name internally during instantiation and return it in the implementation of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply stub it out to do nothing;

```
public string DisplayName { set {} ...}
```

Comment: exactly what I had to do actually, because throwing that exception from the setter was messing with EF ...

Comment: I would, but it's not an answer, because what I am asking is - how can I get rid of that setter ...

Comment: If you get rid of the setter then it will likely break EF.  It IS calling it after all.